# C++ convert a string in a loop to a double

Tags: c++, type-conversion, double

I am trying to get numbers into a string in a loop but convert them immediately and convert it to a double so the 3 numbers can be added and used to get an average. This is my code:

```
string name;
double num = 0, many = 0, total = 0, value = 0;

inputFile.open("Rainfall.txt");


for (int count = 1; count <= 6; count++)
{
    inputFile >> name;

    if (count == 1 || count == 3 || count == 5)
    {

        continue;

    }

    num = stod(name);

    num += total;


}

cout << total << endl;
```

While this gives me a simple one line output of 0 i now need to convert the string to a double. The input file looks like:

january 1.2
feruary 2.3
march 2.4

August 2.3 September 2.4

Comment: total is 0 to start with and you never modify it. You want to add your num variable to total.  Try total += num.  Also, you should step through your code in a debugger to see what's going on.

Comment: Well @AnonMail thanks I cant believe this whole time my only error was me doing num += total instead of what you said. Thank you that works i must have tried everything but that. Thanks.

Comment: You could also read in a string and a double each time through the loop and simply disregard the value of the string instead of reading a string into a double and then keeping count of when you need to `continue`.

Comment: @StephenDocy could you provide me with that code? i did it my way because i couldnt figure that way out

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly better way assuming your input file structure stays intact (does not sanitize inputs) and `std::stod` will fail badly on input that cannot be converted to double. You can simply read your given month and monthly rainfall total into their appropriate variable type at the same time. If you put the whole thing in a while loop, it will keep reading your input until it either reaches the end of the file or the stream has an error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    double total(0.0);
    std::ifstream inputFile("Rainfall.txt");
    if (inputFile.is_open())
    {
        std::string month;
        double rain(0.0);
        while(inputFile >> month >> rain)
        {
            total += rain;
        }
        inputFile.close();  ///< technically not necessary
    }

    std::cout << "total rainfall " << total << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `inputFile.close()` is unnecessary, and you could invert your `is_open` check to early return, saving a level of indentation.

Comment: @Simple I know fstream is a proper RAII object but I personally think it's good practice to close the stream and flush the input buffer.  My coding standards encourage a single point of return, but your point is well taken.